# Export multiple options in $GREP_OPTIONS

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, oh-my-zsh

I use ZSH with "OH MY ZSH".

In "OH MY ZSH" variable `$GREP_OPTIONS` exports with multiple value:

```
$ echo $GREP_OPTIONS
--color=auto --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn
```

But when I try use `grep` I am seeing help for `grep`.

If I set `$GREP_OPTIONS` with single value is all work good

```
$ export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
$ ls -l ~/ | grep .zsh
drwxr-xr-x 11 petr petr   4096 Sep 10 09:23 .oh-my-zsh
drwxr-xr-x  4 petr petr   4096 Sep 24 13:10 .zsh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 petr petr     19 Sep 22 12:24 .zshenv -> /home/petr/.zsh/env
-rw-r--r--  1 petr petr   5141 Sep 23 10:31 .zshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 petr petr     17 Sep 24 12:19 .zsh-update
```

I work in Tmux. But in pure terminal it also occurs.

My ZSH configs on [my GitHub](https://github.com/petrikoz/dotfiles/tree/master/.zsh).

**UPDATE** Example.

Set several `grep` options:

```
$ export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto --exclude-dir=.git'
$ ls -al ~/ | grep zsh
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Search for PATTERN in each FILE or standard input.
PATTERN is, by default, a basic regular expression (BRE).
Example: grep -i 'hello world' menu.h main.c

Regexp selection and interpretation:
  -E, --extended-regexp     PATTERN is an extended regular expression (ERE)
  -F, --fixed-strings       PATTERN is a set of newline-separated fixed strings
  -G, --basic-regexp        PATTERN is a basic regular expression (BRE)
  -P, --perl-regexp         PATTERN is a Perl regular expression
  -e, --regexp=PATTERN      use PATTERN for matching
  -f, --file=FILE           obtain PATTERN from FILE
  -i, --ignore-case         ignore case distinctions
  -w, --word-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole words
  -x, --line-regexp         force PATTERN to match only whole lines
  -z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline

Miscellaneous:
  -s, --no-messages         suppress error messages
  -v, --invert-match        select non-matching lines
  -V, --version             print version information and exit
      --help                display this help and exit
      --mmap                deprecated no-op; evokes a warning

Output control:
  -m, --max-count=NUM       stop after NUM matches
  -b, --byte-offset         print the byte offset with output lines
  -n, --line-number         print line number with output lines
      --line-buffered       flush output on every line
  -H, --with-filename       print the file name for each match
  -h, --no-filename         suppress the file name prefix on output
      --label=LABEL         use LABEL as the standard input file name prefix
  -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
  -q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output
      --binary-files=TYPE   assume that binary files are TYPE;
                            TYPE is 'binary', 'text', or 'without-match'
  -a, --text                equivalent to --binary-files=text
  -I                        equivalent to --binary-files=without-match
  -d, --directories=ACTION  how to handle directories;
                            ACTION is 'read', 'recurse', or 'skip'
  -D, --devices=ACTION      how to handle devices, FIFOs and sockets;
                            ACTION is 'read' or 'skip'
  -r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse
  -R, --dereference-recursive  likewise, but follow all symlinks
      --include=FILE_PATTERN  search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude=FILE_PATTERN  skip files and directories matching FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude-from=FILE   skip files matching any file pattern from FILE
      --exclude-dir=PATTERN  directories that match PATTERN will be skipped.
  -L, --files-without-match  print only names of FILEs containing no match
  -l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
  -c, --count               print only a count of matching lines per FILE
  -T, --initial-tab         make tabs line up (if needed)
  -Z, --null                print 0 byte after FILE name

Context control:
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
  -C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
  -NUM                      same as --context=NUM
      --color[=WHEN],
      --colour[=WHEN]       use markers to highlight the matching strings;
                            WHEN is 'always', 'never', or 'auto'
  -U, --binary              do not strip CR characters at EOL (MSDOS/Windows)
  -u, --unix-byte-offsets   report offsets as if CRs were not there
                            (MSDOS/Windows)

'egrep' means 'grep -E'.  'fgrep' means 'grep -F'.
Direct invocation as either 'egrep' or 'fgrep' is deprecated.
When FILE is -, read standard input.  With no FILE, read . if a command-line
-r is given, - otherwise.  If fewer than two FILEs are given, assume -h.
Exit status is 0 if any line is selected, 1 otherwise;
if any error occurs and -q is not given, the exit status is 2.

Report bugs to: bug-grep@gnu.org
GNU Grep home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/>
General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
```

Set single option:

```
$ export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
$ ls -al ~/ | grep zsh
drwxr-xr-x 11 petr petr   4096 Sep 10 09:23 .oh-my-zsh
drwxr-xr-x  4 petr petr   4096 Sep 24 14:25 .zsh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 petr petr     19 Sep 22 12:24 .zshenv -> /home/petr/.zsh/env
-rw-r--r--  1 petr petr   5141 Sep 23 10:31 .zshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 petr petr     17 Sep 24 12:19 .zsh-update
```

**UPDATE 2**

ZSH version: `zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Grep version: `grep (GNU grep) 2.16`

If add options in command line then work normal:

```
$ unset GREP_OPTIONS
$ ls -al ~/ | grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.git zsh
drwxr-xr-x 11 petr petr   4096 Sep 10 09:23 .oh-my-zsh
drwxr-xr-x  4 petr petr   4096 Sep 24 15:45 .zsh
lrwxrwxrwx  1 petr petr     19 Sep 22 12:24 .zshenv -> /home/petr/.zsh/env
lrwxrwxrwx  1 petr petr     18 Sep 24 15:17 .zshrc -> /home/petr/.zsh/rc
-rw-r--r--  1 petr petr     17 Sep 24 12:19 .zsh-update
```

Comment: Can you include, in your question, the way you set `GREP_OPTIONS` and use `grep` and the resulting message?

Comment: @Anthon I updated question.

Comment: can you add your grep version?

Comment: Grep version 2.16

Comment: What happens if you only set `--exclude-dir=.git`?

Comment: I don't run into that problem with zsh 4.3.17 and GNU grep 2.10

Comment: If I unset `GREP_OPTIONS` and set options in command line (without environment variable) then `grep` work normal. But if I set two or more options in environment variable then `grep` not work.

Comment: My ZSH version 5.0.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: please avoid chatting here. Update in your Question,  instead.

Comment: @Tejas is right. I updated question.

Comment: Do you set GREP_COLOR(S) variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've made `grep` an alias for `grep $GREP_OPTIONS`. Don't do that: the GNU `grep` command itself parses the `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable.

If you want to put options to a command in a variable, make that variable an array, and don't export it (you can't export arrays anyway, environment variables have string values only).

```
LS_OPTIONS=(--color=auto -q)
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
```

If you have a list of options with a string value (for example because it was passed through the environment), you'll need to split it. The downside of this approach compared to using an array is that whitespace will then be option separators, you can't have whitespace in an option. Use `$=VAR` to split the value of `VAR` into separate words on whitespace (or more generally on characters in `IFS`), like other shells do (zsh won't expand wildcards with `$=VAR`, use `$~VAR` to expand wildcards and `$=~VAR` to do both).

P.S. `GREP_OPTIONS` is dangerous because it applies in scripts that may be relying on the exact set of options that they pass to `grep`. `--color=auto` is about the only safe thing you can put there; it's even [officially deprecated since grep 2.21](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/NEWS?id=d930f765041bb2ad936056ddfdad60042d44bd9d). It would be better to make `grep` itself an alias (and also `egrep` and `fgrep` if you use them):

```
my_grep_options=(--color=auto --exclude-dir=.cvs --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn)
alias grep='grep $my_grep_options' egrep='grep -E $my_grep_options' fgrep='grep -F $my_grep_options'
```

Comment: Your solution is working perfectly! Thanks